# IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted error

Tags: python, macos, os.path

I am working with os.path in python2 on MacOS 10.15.2 and am unable to open an image from my working directory.  Here is the code:

```
'''
# JDoe_JSmith_1_4_3: Change pixels in an image.
'''
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
import numpy as np  # "as" lets us use standard abbreviations

#Read the image data
# Get the directory of this python script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
# Build an absolute filename from directory + filename
filename = os.path.join(directory, 'woman.jpg')
# Read the image data into an array
img = plt.imread(filename)

###
# Change a region if condition is True
###

height = len(img)
width = len(img[0])
for r in range(155):
    for c in range(width):
        if sum(img[r][c])>500: # brightness R+G+B goes up to 3*255=765
            img[r][c]=[255,0,255] # R + B = magenta
       # if sum(img[r][c])

###
# Show the image data
###

#Show the image data
# Create figure with 1 subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Show the image data in a subplot
ax.imshow(img, interpolation='none')
# Show the figure on the screen



fig.show()
```

Any workarounds for this or am I doing something wrong?  Any help is greaty appreciated.

Here is an image of the error if it may help:
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTQfi.png)

I should also mention that this ran perfectly on Windows 10; I am only getting an error on MacOS.

Comment: Have you verified the values of `directory` and `filename`?

Comment: What do you mean by verifying the directory and filename?  Sorry, I am a student and ill-experienced in terminology.